# Is there any way to login to sql server by internet?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I have a server (which i installed windows server 2008 r2 and SQL server 2008 r2 on it) in another city, i installed SQL server 2008 r2 on my laptop too, i want to know how i can login to the SQL server which installed on the server in another city by internet and valid IP?

Comment: What did you tried? Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard sql connection string used in any programming language will work.  Or you could open up Sql Management studio and type in the IP of the server.  The problem you face is that the server is most likely behind a firewall blocking port 1433.  Either hardware or software, port 1433 isn't typically just 'open'.  Try telnetting into the target IP on port 1433 to see if firewalls are in the way.  If your screen clears, it means you are clear to connect to the IP and then the only thing getting in your way is authentication.  I imagine you have SQL server user accounts that you can use to connect.

Comment: IF port 1433 be open, there isn't any problem?

Comment: If port 1433 is open all the way to the server and you have credentials, there will be no problem.